# How do I programmatically set a MatSelect's MatSelectTrigger?

Tags: angular, typescript, mat-select

Given a reference to a `MatSelect` instance, how do I go about programmatically setting its `MatSelectTrigger` template? Per the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api), there is a settable `customTrigger` property, but I wasn't able to find any documentation on the `MatSelectTrigger` class or how to dynamically create one.

My goal is to have a directive that sets up a `<mat-select-trigger>` component on a `MatSelect` dynamically to reduce copy+paste.

In the meantime I am manually manipulating the DOM on the `selectionChange` event, but this is hacky and prone to breaking.

Is there an official and safe way to, inside a directive and with a reference to a `MatSelect`, give it a dynamic trigger template?

Thanks!

Comment: Note shure to undestand what your want ? All documentation available https://material.angular.io/components/select/api

Comment: @TimothyALCAIDE for example, see `customTrigger` in their documentation - how would one programmatically use that property to create a `<mat-select-trigger>` in an existing `<mat-select>`? There is no examples or documentation on `customTrigger` that I can find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there is a settable customTrigger property, but I wasn't able to find any documentation on the MatSelectTrigger class or how to dynamically create one.

`customTrigger` is not a settable property. It's a `@ContentChild` type. This means that the `mat-select` expects a content projection of type `MatSelectTrigger`.

This is the excerpted code from the [source file](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/select/select.ts):

```
 @ContentChild(MAT_SELECT_TRIGGER) customTrigger: MatSelectTrigger;
```

---

#### Solution

To dynamically supply a different template into the `mat-select-trigger`, you will need to create a wrapper component as following:

**mat-select-wrapper.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>

  <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple>

    <mat-select-trigger>
      <!-- NOTICE HERE: We inject triggerTemplate into mat-select-trigger -->
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="triggerTemplate"></ng-container>
    </mat-select-trigger>

    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" 
                [value]="topping">{{topping}}
    </mat-option>

  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**mat-select-wrapper.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input, TemplateRef} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mat-select-wrapper',
  templateUrl: 'mat-select-wrapper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['mat-select-wrapper.component.css'],
})
export class MatSelectWrapperComponent {

  // Accept a custom template from outside and display it.
  @Input()
  public triggerTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

  public toppings = new FormControl();

  public toppingList = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion'];
}
```

**Parent component that uses the wrapper**

```
<app-mat-select-wrapper [triggerTemplate]="myTemplate"></app-mat-select-wrapper>

<ng-template #myTemplate>
  Hello! You can provide any kind of HTML here.
</ng-template>
```

You will need to add more `@Input` so you can pass in different values through the wrapper and into the actual `mat-select`. Such as `toppingList` that is used by the `mat-option`.

Comment: Thank you! It appears the real answer is "you can't set it programmatically", but templates seem like a better option and I'm successfully implementing the concept now :)

Comment: @Tor My pleasure!